# htaccess with multiple get for activation url

Tags: .htaccess

I have this following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?p=$1
```

This allows me to do the following:

domain.com/activate/

I wanted to add an 2nd parameter: domain/activate/aSdxa2osd1plD

where index.php?p=activate&h=aSdxa2osd1plD

I tried several htaccess files, but they don't seem to work.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# to handle domain/activate
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

# to handle domain/activate/aSdxa2osd1plD
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&h=$2 [L,QSA]
```